# iOS app device test with iOS 4.3, 4.2, 4.1, 4.0, 5.0, iOS

Tags: ios, ios4

As of today, the latest sub version of iOS 4 SDK is 4.3, and iOS 5 beta and GM maybe coming this Septemebr.

If we are developing an app that support iOS 4.0 or above, do we need to perform device test on iDevice with iOS 4.0, iOS 4.1, iOS 4.2, iOS 4.3? Or if the app works well and tested well on iOS4.3 and I developed the app with iOS SDK 4.0 only, can I deduce that it can works well in iOS 4.0/4.1/4.2? I have this question because I have only a iDevice with iOS 4.3 installed and could not find an official reference that different iOS 4.x version is compatible.

Apart from testing the app in iOS 4.3 device, I will also test it in iOS 5 beta/GM.

What is your common practice to perform this kind of device compatibility test?

Thank you very much and your expert experience can help me.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, if your App only uses iOS 4.0 SDK's features, and it runs fine on an iOS 4.3 devices, it should also runs on other devices with iOS 4.0 and above (but below iOS 5).

But there is no better way to make sure your App dose work as expected on different iOS versions, unless you try it. That's why we need to buy more than one iOS device and at least install some mainly release version of iOS in them (iOS 4.1, iOS 4.3.5 and iOS 5 beta7 for example).

If you have problem in buying so many iOS devices, you should at least test your App in different simulators, a lot of compatibility problems can be find out in simulator, but not all of them. So you should also invite some friends or users to test your Apps for you.

I am using TestFlight to send my users the test version of my App. And you can send it via email, too.

Finally, if you don't want to do any of that, all you can do is pray that your Apps doesn't have problem :)

Comment: As I am uing Mac OS Lion and Xcode 4, can I run iOS 4.0 simulator in it?
I think it is quite difficult to get a iPhone device which is still having iOS 4.0 or iOs 4.1 for device testing.

Comment: If you think there is nearly no user still using iOS 4.0 or iOS 4.1, you'd better just set your "Deployment Target" to iOS 4.3. Otherwise you should take the risk.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I have the SDK set to 4.3 and the minimum level set to 4.1. When I make use of classes or methods that are in 4.3 but not 4.1, I first test in code if the class or method exist. The few devices I have run 4.3 and the iOS 5 beta. I sometimes test earlier versions in the simulator. Generally this has worked well for me.

The upgrade rate is very high. Ever since Apple made iOS upgrades free, a high percentage of iOS users upgrade to the latest version within weeks of release.